# Using iPhone's HDR feature

Tags: iphone, ios5, photo, hdr

I am trying to create an iPhone photo app that defaults to HDR mode when taking pictures with iPhone 4/4s. I do not want users to have the non-HDR option for taking photo with my app if users have iPhone 4/4s. However, HDR mode is not available in UIImagePickerController. Can you give me pointers on how to enable the iPhone app to "automatically default to HDR mode" ? (I am developing on iOS5) Many thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution to your question?